# adding optgroup using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am having an issue were when i add an optgroup to my dropdown menu using jquery its not showing up.  Checking the source I can see that the closing tag has been placed at the end thereby closing the optgroup before the contents have been appened.  I have tried various ways of adding the content

So at the top of the script i have created a hash which has a server environment, this retuns a list of

top of the page:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
serverList["BERT"] = ["server1", "server2"
```

function createServerListNEW(env) {

```
    if (env != "") {

        if (! serverList[env]) {
            fadeInfoText("ERROR! No Lookup for " + env);
            return;
        }

        $("#ss1").append("<optgroup label='" + env + "'>");

        for (var j = 0; j < serverList[env].length; j ++) {
            serveritem = serverList[env][j]
            $("#ss1").append("<option value='" + serveritem + "'>" + serveritem + "</option>");
        }

        $("#ss1").append("</optgroup>");
        $("#ss1").multiselect('refresh');
    }
}
```

OUTPUT AFTER RUNNING

```
    <select title="Server Selection" multiple="multiple" name="ss1" id="ss1" size="15" style="display: none; border-color: black; background-color: white;">  
<optgroup label="BERT"></optgroup>
<option value="server1">server1</option>
<option value="server2">server2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When you append an element, the entire element get's inserted, not just the opening tag. Look into one of jQuery's wrap functions. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qpp3mzf4/

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you create an element.

When `$("#ss1").append("<optgroup label='" + env + "'>");` executes, there is already `</optgroup>`. So you need to remove the last append.

And then you'll have to append the `<option>` to `<optgroup>` using `find`

```
for (var j = 0; j < serverList[env].length; j ++) {
   serveritem = serverList[env][j]
   $("#ss1").find("optgroup").append("<option/>", { 
        value : serveritem,
        text : serveritem
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is that i have multiple ENV check boxes on a page and i want to have a list of servers under each env. so if i click the BERT checkbox then the optgroup BERT will be created and then all the servers whichares in the array are placed under that list.  again is someone clicks another ENV then another optgroup should be created with the servers for that env under it also.

I also want it so that if someone unchecks a selection then that optgroup and servers are removed but havent got to that part yet :)

OK i managed to get it to work with the following code, the append you suggestion doesnt work with IE8 as the contents of the dropdown are missing which is an issue i worked through before:

```
function createServerList(env) {

    if (env != "") {

        if (! serverList[env]) {
            fadeInfoText("ERROR! No Lookup for " + env);
            return;
        }

        $("#ss1").append("<optgroup label='" + env + " Server List'>");

        for (var j = 0; j < serverList[env].length; j ++) {
            serveritem = serverList[env][j]
            $("#ss1").find("optgroup").append("<option value='" + serveritem + "'>" + serveritem + "</option>");
        }

        $("#ss1").multiselect('refresh');
    }
}
```

Many thanks for the suggestions and pointing me in the right direction.  Now onto the remove if unchecked lol :)